# Storing 16-bit ints with scale and offset as floats in HDF5

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I have some data collected from DACs; they're 16-bit ints. To convert them to meaningful units (volts, for example) I also have a scale and offset, both stored as floats.

I'm looking to write this out as an HDF5 file using h5py. So far, I'm just creating a float dataset and writing the numbers out; however, this is giving me really big files. Looking at the documentation, [there's a scale-offset filter](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#scale-offset-filter) that looks like it might help -- however, it doesn't look like I can feed it my scale and offset information -- instead, I'd feed it a number of significant digits to store.

Is this right? Is there an elegant way to do this? If I really need to just specify a number of digits (probably in base 10?) I'm guessing I'd store 6, as you can fit 65535 in six digits. Or maybe 5, as the docs say it's "the number of digits after the decimal point to retain"?

And yes, I know I could just store the ints, with scale and offset as attributes.

Comment: I read about the scale-offset filter and it seems it's not what you want. I guess you have to do the way of storing the ints  with scale and offset as attributes and then do the conversion yourself, which is probably also the most straightforward way to achieve that.